# how to paint over an existing material with vertex paint?

Tags: shaders, color, vertex-paint

I have the following material [image]

[image]

I was hoping to just paint a lets say a red color using the vertex paint method found in sculpt mode but I cannot set the shader properly for that, I have tried overlay/mix and so on but not able to get the desired effect, I want to completely paint over some part of the model with my desired color, how do I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: you have to connect the color attribute to the factor, if that doesn't work, pls provide blend file

Comment: do i have to paint it white or black then? I just tried that and nothing happens, I have added an example of it example file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your blend file you forgot to choose the color attribute:

[image]

You have to choose "Color" so that Blender takes that vertex color attribute into account. Your color attribute node was empty.

Yes "normally" you would paint black and white to have full or no color, but of course you could choose any color if you wanna paint shades of colors.

Comment: Ahh i can't believe i had missed that, thanks a lot!